# combining pdb file,xml config file and a dll into a single file

Tags: .net-assembly

I have three files in the bin folder. While building,I am getting these files.one dll file,one application file(which has no extension),one xml configuration file(which has .exe extension). How it is possible to combine these 3 files into a single exe?..I am running C# winform application

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to combine them, but you don't need to distribute the .xml or .pdb files, they are just for debugging.